# Pagination large text file and display on the screen

Tags: android, pagination, text-files

[ANDROID] The first, Thanks for your time and i'm sorry if you do not understand what i talk about. And Can you ask me more detail.

Hi! I am a developer. I making a functions about reading book from txt file on device storage. I want read text in file, then pagination text and display each page on the screen.

To do pagination text, I tried use:

- StaticLayout.
- PageFactory. (https://github.com/fengjuan/android_eReader/blob/master/Reader/src/com/example/minireader/BookPageFactory.java)

It works fine if my text is short (~10kb text file), the number of letters in a screen is less. When i increase text data (~6mb text file) and the number of letters in a screen, It works very slow.

I was referred "eReader Prestigio: Book Reader" app and see that this app load text data from file then pagination very fast, display text on the screen very beautiful.

I did take a few weeks to learn about it. But I do not find the solution for my issue.  Who can have any suggestion for pagination text faster like "eReader Prestigio" app?

You can refer "eReader Prestigio" at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prestigio.ereader

Comment: Show your code that you use for pagination now.

Comment: Is it about a .txt file? Unformatted text?

Comment: @greenapps: yes.! It's unformatted text. You can download a text book file in the internet. and open by "eReader Prestigio" you can see that.

Comment: No intentions to do so. You better show your pagination code. And the code to read a page from the file.

Comment: @greenapps: I see that when i read text in the file is fast but when pagination is working slow. When use `StaticLayout` i put all text and textview Paint to do it. And with PageFactory i shared sample code above.